# Is this PHP Object design approach good or bad? - looking for critique

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I am relatively new to working with PHP in an OOP way. In my newest project i am going to create a site which will load a lot of entries from SQL-database and then send these to the view for output.

While fiddling with how to do this in the best way, I have created the code as listed below:

```
class entryHandler {

//Store database connection
protected $database;

//List of all entries as multidimensional array fetched from SQL.
private $entriesSQL = array();

//List of all entries (as objects) will be stored in our $entries array
private $entriesObjects = array();


/*
 * 
 * Upon construct
 * 
 */
public function __construct($database) {

    //Check if database class has been passed correctly.
    //Else we exit, since we can not function without it!
    if (isset($database)) {

        $this -> database = $database;

        //Get events
        if ($entriesSQL = $this -> getEventsFromSQL()) {
            // Set SQL entries
            $this -> setEntriesSQL($entriesSQL);

            //And turn them into an array of objects
            $this -> setEntryObjects();
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'No database connection has been established. Exiting execution.';
        exit();
    }
}


/*
 * Setter for entriesSQL
 */
private function setEntriesSQL($entriesSQL) {
    $this -> entriesSQL = $entriesSQL;
}


/*
 * Getter for entriesSQL
 */
public function getEntriesSQL() {
    return $this -> entriesSQL;
}


/*
 * Setter for entry objects
 * 
 */
private function setEntryObjects() {
    foreach ($this -> getEntriesSQL() as $key => $val) {
        //entryID, entryUserID, entryTitle, entryTimeStart, entryTimeEnd
        array_push($this -> entriesObjects, new entry($val['entryID'], $val['entryUserID'], $val['entryTitle'], $val['entryTimeStart'], $val['entryTimeEnd']));
    }
}


/*
 * 
 * Getter for entry objects
 * 
 */
public function getEntryObjects() {
    return $this -> entriesObjects;
}

/*
 * 
 * This function grabs events from SQL and return multidimensional-array of content.
 * 
 */
private function getEventsFromSQL() {
    //Define the SQL query
    $SQL = '...snippet...';

    if ($entriesSQL = $this -> database -> read($SQL)) {
        //Entries collected, return them.
        return $entriesSQL;
    }
    else {
        //Error occured. Log it and return false.
        return false;
    }
}

}


class entry {

var $entryID;
var $entryUserID;
var $entryTitle;
var $entryTimeStart;
var $entryTimeEnd;

public function __construct($entryID, $entryUserID, $entryTitle, $entryTimeStart, $entryTimeEnd) {
    $this -> setEntryID($entryID);
    $this -> setEntryUserID($entryUserID);
    $this -> setEntryTitle($entryTitle);
    $this -> setEntryTimeStart($entryTimeStart);
    $this -> setEntryTimeEnd($entryTimeEnd);
}

/*
 * Setter for entryID
 */
private function setEntryID($entryID) {
    $this -> entryID = $entryID;
}

/*
 * Getter for entryID
 */
public function getEntryID() {
    return $this -> entryID;
}



/*
 * Setter for entryUserID
 */
private function setEntryUserID($entryUserID) {
    $this -> entryUserID = $entryUserID;
}

/*
 * Getter for entryUserID
 */
public function getEntryUserID() {
    return $this -> entryUserID;
}



/*
 * Setter for entryTitle
 */
private function setEntryTitle($entryTitle) {
    $this -> entryTitle = $entryTitle;
}

/*
 * Getter for entryTitle
 */
public function getEntryTitle() {
    return $this -> entryTitle;
}



/*
 * Setter for entryTimeStart
 */
private function setEntryTimeStart($entryTimeStart) {
    $this -> entryTimeStart = $entryTimeStart;
}

/*
 * Getter for entryTimeStart
 */
public function getEntryTimeStart() {
    return $this -> entryTimeStart;
}


/*
 * Setter for entryTimeEnd
 */
private function setEntryTimeEnd($entryTimeEnd) {
    $this -> entryTimeEnd = $entryTimeEnd;
}

/*
 * Getter for entryTimeEnd
 */
public function getEntryTimeEnd() {
    return $this -> entryTimeEnd;
}
}
```

Now, the class "entryHandler" is loaded from my controller (in another PHP-file) like this:

```
    //Instantiate calenderHandler and pass our database handler to it.
    $entryHandler = new entryHandler($database);

    //Load template
    $template -> calendarEntries = $this -> renderEntries($entryHandler -> getEntryObjects());



/*
 * 
 * This functions renders entries content for view.
 * Returns string with content.
 * 
 */
private function renderEntries($entries) {

    $entriesContent = '';

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        $entriesContent .= '{
                                title: "' . $entry -> getEntryTitle() . '",
                                start: "' . $entry -> getEntryTimeStart() . '",
                                end:   "' . $entry -> getEntryTimeEnd() . '"
                            }, ';
    }

    //Right trim entries string, so that we do not add trailing comma to last entry in list.
    $entriesContent = rtrim($entriesContent, ', ');

    //And return content to parse it to view.
    return $entriesContent;
}
 }
```

Is this a bad design pattern? Is there anything that I should do in a another way? Is there some kind of redudancy in this code? - Something that I should be aware of?

Thank to everyone for your time.

Greetings,
fischer

Comment: This should be on code review. (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just one hint about constructors: Clean Your constructors from any logic. They should only to set values, every logic should be extracted to private methods to keep it clean and scalable.
If You need to prepare some values before using the object, do it "lazy way" - prepare it just in the methods where You need it by calling private methods.

Comment: Don't forget about tags inside function comment like `@param string $arg  @return int|bool`

Comment: For your to-do list - learn about autoloading approaches (like PSR-0) as these will affect your class/folder names. Secondly, it's not wrong to have a space either side of the reference operator (`->`) but I think it looks odd, personally. Lastly where you've got a `private` method or attribute, decide if you really want to make it inaccessible to a child class - these could be `protected` and thus available via inheritance.

Comment: You look to be off to a great start with OOP, among the other things mentioned in the Answers and Comments, I would perhaps recommend looking at and following the [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) coding style, it may come handy later down the line if you go down the route of Autoloading, and maybe even if you realise something to others.

Comment: Thank you all. I will remember to add tags inside function comments as metal_fan pointed out. Too I will have a look at PSR-2 coding style! :) Thanks Aran!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you're doing is throwing around the data.
This might not necessarily be wrong, but you could do something else. Instead of storing all SQL entries in an array, how about:

- Fetch data from the database.
- Create an object that holds this data. ( Object relation mapping )

So instead of throwing around actual data, you throw around objects, containing data.
This is a good idea, because it will be easy to change the way data behaves, or add a way the data is extracted, or whatever you might need.

Also what you're doing, is not necessarily classified OOP. You just contained a lot of functions in a class.

Create classes to do what you need, and keep classes as small as possible. Everytime you do something that the class you're in, is not created to do, create a new class that handles what you need.

**OOP example**

A great way to learn how to do OOP, is to watch how others did it. I would recommend you looking up other projects and see how they did.

[Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) - A complex php framework using OOP.
[Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)
[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
[LavarelPHP](http://laravel.com/)

Comment: Symfony2 is quite a complex framework to look at to learn, a better framework would perhaps be [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [LaravelPHP](http://laravel.com) these frameworks are a lot simpler IMO for a begineer in OOP and good starting grounds for PHP OOP, and PHP Frameworks.

Comment: I will add them to the examples, thanks.

Comment: Thanks... Your point about me just throwing data around was exactly what the kind of thing, that I was concerned about!

Also great to have pointed out some frameworks to start from. I have just - as a cause of yours and Arans' comments dived into Lavarel. Looks great. Will have a go at it :)

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much agree with answer from Kao. Anyway if you really want to do this yourself instead of using any DBAL, I would recommend you to read some [docs on ORMs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/architecture.html).

In your code, allowing construct to handle many things at a time is a bad idea. Clean and separate them. Use dependency injections instead of creating objects inside classes/methods.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment since you are "agreeing" with another answer and introducing terms such as dependency injection which you aren't making clear for the OP.